# JavaScript - How can I replace string with certain char in to a function

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

How can I do this using regex, replacing every string with `!` wrapped in function:

Examples:

- `3!` => `fact(3)`
- `2.321!` => `fact(2.321)`
- `(3.2+1)!` => `fact(3.2+1)`
- `(sqrt(2)+2/2^2)!` => `fact(sqrt(2)+2/2^2)`

Comment: Look into the [Javascript `replace` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own answer i just found out was:

```
Number.prototype.fact = function(n) {return fact(this,2)}
str = str.replace(/[\d|\d.\d]+/g, function(n) {return "(" + n + ")"}).replace(/\!/g, ".fact()")
```

But I'll see if the other answers might be much better, think they are

Comment: `[\d|\d.\d]` isn't doing what you probably think it is.  It's a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches one character at a time: a digit, a pipe (`|`), or a period (`\.`).  This is probably what you're looking for: `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

Answer (score 1):

Given your examples, you don't need a regex at all:

```
var s = "3!"; //for example

if (s[s.length-1] === "!")
    s = "fact(" + s.substr(0, s.length-1) + ")";
```

Not doubling the parentheses for the last case just requires another test:

```
var s = "(sqrt(2)+2/2^2)!"; //for example

if (s[s.length-1] === "!") {
    if(s.length > 1 && s[0] === "(" && s[s.length-2] === ")") 
        s = "fact" + s.substr(0, s.length-1);
    else
        s = "fact(" + s.substr(0, s.length-1) + ")";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var testArr =  [];
testArr.push("3!");
testArr.push("2.321!");
testArr.push("(3.2+1)!");
testArr.push("(sqrt(2)+2/2^2)!");

//Have some fun with the name. Why not?
function ohIsThatAFact(str) {
    if (str.slice(-1)==="!") {
         str = str.replace("!","");
         if(str[0]==="(" && str.slice(-1)===")") 
             str = "fact"+str;
         else 
             str = "fact("+str+")";
    }
    return str;
}

for (var i = 0; i < testArr.length; i++) {
    var testCase = ohIsThatAFact(testArr[i]);
    document.write(testCase + "<br />");
}
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kaTwp/)

Answer (score 0):

```
"(sqrt(2)+2/2^2)!".replace(/(.*)!/g, "fact($1)");
```

[Fiddle with it!](http://jsfiddle.net/tB3F9/)

`(.*)!`

- Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 `(.*)`

  - Match any single character that is not a line break character `.`
  - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`
- Match the character “!” literally `!`

Comment: I assumed there might be other characters in the string that do not need to be put in fact(...)

Answer (score 0):

Here is as the op requested; using regexp:

```
"3*(2+1)!".replace(/([1-9\.\(\)\*\+\^\-]+)/igm,"fact($1)");
```

You might end up with double parentheses:

```
"(2+1)!".replace(/([1-9\.\(\)\*\+\^\-]+)/igm,"fact($1)");
```